# Is it possible for a submitted form that has been updated to same page without refresh to be accessed by friendly url at a later time?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Lets say I have a form that a user submits which is then handled server side and updated to the same page without page refresh. Can the results that were updated to this page be accessed by a friendly url at a later time?

HTML:

```
<form id="search" method="GET">
    <input id="tags" type="text" name="b" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>

<span id="details"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#search').submit(function () {
            $.getJSON('/_search', {
                b: $('input[name="b"]').val(),
            }, function (data) {
                $("#details").text(data.details);
                $("#search")[0].reset(); /*clear the form after details are updated*/
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/_search')
    def details():
    thetag = request.args.get('b')
    return jsonify(details=thetag)

@app.route('/')
    def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The code above is working as intended. The results are displayed to details without the page refreshing. Is it possible to access these results at a later time by the user going to a friendly url? i.e. /search/item_being_searched

Comment: It could be done if you set a cookie/localStorage/etc in the users’ browser and load data from there. If it’s possible to do that in your app’s environment.

Comment: I'm using flask as the web framework if that helps any. What if the user has never visited the webpage before but clicks a link that routes to /search/item_being_searched. In that instance, there would be no cookie data to load the results from if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: Just check for cookie data - if it’s there load it, if it isn’t there display the basic form. I’m not saying that this is the only solution, but I would give it a try anyway :)

Comment: Somehow you have to identify the user and connect the form data with her/him, otherwise you don’t know what to display (with a pretty URL you cannot encode the data in parameters), and a cookie is just for that

Comment: And for the URL query parameters: you don’t have to refresh the page - write the code such that it can parse your query parameters, and fill out the form if they are set on page load

Comment: I managed to get it to work how I wanted. I appreciate the help and ideas. I ended up creating a dynamic route that renders search.html page and passes a variable which contains result data to page.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is solved:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a dynamic route that renders search.html page and passes a variable which contains result data to page.

```
@app.route('/<item_being_searched>')
def searched_item(search_name):
    #do stuff with item_being_searched here that mimmicks form submit
    #output to be passed as variable details to template search.html
    return render_template('search.html',details=output )
```

Still need to do error checking, but this does what I had in mind.